# Compare two QAbstractItemModels

Tags: c++, algorithm, qt

I'm trying to figure out an efficient algorithm that takes in two QAbstractItemModels (trees) (A,B) and computes the differences between them, such that I get a list of Items that are not present in A (but are in B - added), or items that have been modified / deleted.

The only current way I can think of is doing a Breadth search of A for every item item in B. But this doesn't seem very efficient. Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: You should clarify your question. It is not clear for me, what you mean by "differences". There may be 2 kind of diffs: difference in tree structure and difference in node values. It is not clear, how do you want to compare nodes (what data should be used as a key)?

Comment: You could probably build two `std::vector<QModelIndex>`, then sort them and using custom comparator (that takes the data from the corresponding model) and then use `std::set_difference` (also with a similar comparator) to get the difference. This should be O(n log(n)) as opposed to O(n^2). Or if you start with empty trees - you can maintain the difference upon each insert/delete to either of the models. But as @Saz said, more details are needed.

Comment: @Rostislav - that might work for primitive values, but I highly doubt it will work for a functional data tree.

Comment: @ddriver I don't see how the data type matters here. It's just an additional lookup - think of sorting an array of pointers to large data objects where a comparator just does `*left < *right` instead of `left < right`. But the point still stands, even the overall problem being solved by the OP is not clear, so it's all a moot point.

Comment: You're asking how to do an oriented graph comparison. Qt doesn't implement it for you, so from now on, the question should be treated as a CS question...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using magic?

Seriously though, this is a very broad question, especially if we consider the fact it is an `QAbstractItemModels` and not a `QAbstractListModel`. For a list it would be much simpler, but an abstract item model implements a tree structure so there are a lot of variables.

- do you check for total item count
- do you check for item count per level
- do you check if item is contained in both models
- if so, is it contained at the same level
- if so, is it contained at the same index
- is the item in its original state or has it been modified

You need to make all those considerations and come up with an efficient solution. And don't expect it will as simple as a "by the book algorithm". Good news, since you are dealing with isolated items, it will be easier than trying to do that for text, and in the case of the latter, you can't hope to get anywhere nearly as concise as with isolated items. I've had my fair share of absurdly mindless github diff results.

And just in case that's your actual goal, it will be much easier to achieve by tracking the history of the derived data set than doing a blind comparison. Tracking history is much easier if you want to establish what is added, what is deleted, what is moved and what is modified. Because it will consider the actual event flow rather than just the end result comparison. Especially if you don't have any persistent ID scheme implemented. Is there a way to tell if item X has been deleted or moved to a new level/index and modified and stuff like that.

Also, worry about efficiency only after you have empirically established a performance issue. Some algorithms may seem overly complex, but modern machines are overly fast, and unless you are running that in a tight loop you shouldn't really worry about it. In the end, it doesn't boil down to how complex it is, it boils down to whether it is fast enough or not.